# SQL: doing several joins to evaluate different columns

Tags: sql-server, join, view, union

I'm quite new to SQL but use it a lot now in my work now (Microsoft SQL Server).

So the issue is this: I collect data that is atypical for a certain column.

Let's say I got different Burgers and they should have a standardized calories value. So I did this with a query

```
------------------------------------------
| Burger | calories  | numBurgers  | Rank |
------------------------------------------
| Chicken|  600      | 20          | 1    |
| Chicken|  400      |  3          | 2    |
| Beef   |  700      | 35          | 1    |
| Beef   |  850      | 4           | 2    |
-------------------------------------------
```

To get a list of all the "wrong" burgers I use a temporary table and filter out GroupRank = 1

```
USE database;
GO
WITH GapRanking AS 
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Burger, calories, COUNT(calories),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Burger ORDER BY COUNT(calories) DESC) AS Rank
)

SELECT * FROM GapRanking
WHERE Rank <> 1
```

...

I get all combinations of Burgers and calories that are not "standard"

Then I do an Inner Join with the original table and all columns on the one above.

```
SELECT * FROM BaseTable as base
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM GapRanking
  WHERE Rank <> 1) AS err
ON (base.Burgers = err.Burgers
   AND base.calories = err.calories)
```

This way I get a table with complete information about the "not-standard" burgers. So far so good.

Now I want to add other rows where there is a deviation in another criteria, price for example, not just calories and add it to the list if its not already there.

So I thought of UNION or JOIN.

So what is the best approach. UNION the above query with the same query just different column (price instead of calories)?

Or do a JOIN with the same query just different column (price instead of calories)?

The code gets quite "ugly" and I'm not sure if I do the right approach here.
Also because of me using the temporary table using WITH a UNION does not seem possible so easily. 
I'm really glad for any ideas here. Cheers

Comment: Union returns the rows from two tables. Why would you not use it? What exact join(s) query are you comparing to & what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sub-query and join below is just sudo-code not actual you can follow like this way

```
select t1.*, t2.required_colum
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Burger, calories, COUNT(calories),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Burger ORDER BY COUNT(calories) DESC) AS Rank
) as t1
join 
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Burger, calories, COUNT(calories),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Burger ORDER BY COUNT(calories) DESC) AS Rank
) as t2
on t1.colname = t2.colname
where t1.Rank != 1 and t2.Rank != 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zaynul. The problem is I don't want all the burgers but only the ones that have rank higher than 1 (see above), so I need    WHERE Rank <> 1.   Problem is, I can only do this using WITH, otherwise I get an error using WHERE on the ROW_NUMBER function.

Comment: no man in subquery u can use where clause like  just where t1.rn！=1 it works like charm

Comment: @Matt44just edited my sudo.code you can try that way

Comment: ok I tried it and it works indeed, cool, thanks! Strange because I tried something similar before and didn't work out. Only thing is I have to do a FULL JOIN to combine all the errors in one table. But filtering out the Ranks works like a charm, have a recommend! I work it out now and let you know. Cheers!

Comment: if it helps accept my answer with upvote please thanks @Matt444

Comment: Alright, I did but it says I need more reputation to make the upvote visible.